# How to set statement timeout for query execution

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In my web app some postgres sql queries take along time for execution.
I want set statement timeout for only part of them.

One part of queries must canceled by timeout, but other must work without any restriction.

In postgres exist statement_timeout function.

How to wrap SqlAlchemy query with statement_timeout function?

Like this:

```
SET statement_timeout TO 1000; -- timeout for one second
<sqlalchemy generated query>;
RESET statement_timeout; -- reset
```

Perfect way for me set timeout for query like this:

```
users = session.query(User).timeout(0.5).all()
```

SqlAlchemy must: 1) set statement timeout 2) execute query and return result 3) reset statement timeout for current session

May be other way to set timeout for query execution?

**UPDATE 1.** My solution

My solution is a custom connection proxy (tested with psycopg2==2.4 and SQLAlchemy==0.6.6):

```
from sqlalchemy.interfaces import ConnectionProxy

class TimeOutProxy(ConnectionProxy):
    def cursor_execute(self, execute, cursor, statement, parameters, context, executemany):

        timeout = context.execution_options.get('timeout', None)

        if timeout:
            c = cursor._parent.cursor()
            c.execute('SET statement_timeout TO %d;' % int(timeout * 1000))
            c.close()

        return execute(cursor, statement, parameters, context)


engine = create_engine(URL, proxy=TimeOutProxy(), pool_size=1, max_overflow=0)
```

This solution without reseting statement_timeout, because each SqlAlchemy query executed in isolated transaction and
statement_timeout defined inside current transaction.

Usage example (timeout pаram in seconds):

```
Session.query(Author).execution_options(timeout=0.001).all()

Session.bind.execute(text('select * from author;') \
      .execution_options(timeout=0.001)) \
      .fetchall()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the extensions provided with SQLAlchemy <= 0.6:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/06/orm/interfaces.html

There are hooks where you could stick in your code for individual operations.

SQLAlchemy 0.7+ now has an event system...there might be something similar. See

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/events.html

Comment: first link is broken