# How to set query execution timeout in sqlalchemy sessions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using MSSQL as my database. It is taking too long to respond back for some queries and sometimes it is resulting in deadlocks. Hence i want to set custom timeout for queries. I got some custom solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492366/how-to-set-statement-timeout-for-query-execution) but it is for psycopg2 and sqlalchemy but i need it for MSSQL and sqlalchemy. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.