# setting a query timeout in sqlalchemy calls

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I am trying to set a query timeout in sqlalchemy calls so that a `session.query(TableName).filter_by(..)` would time out if the query is taking too long (because the DB is locked due to too many other clients accessing the DB). Is this possible via some global parameter I pass to `create_engine()`? From the documentation I did not see such an option

Comment: That's DB specific, so which DB are you using?

Comment: I am using postgres but need this also on sql server

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492366/how-to-set-statement-timeout-for-query-execution